# Trying to save php operators as string in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

I am using a form to save the inputs from the user in database - most of the content consist of

`<` `>` `=` `>=` `<=` `<>`

HTML form uses specialcharacters like this to replace them like `&gt;` `&lt;`

How can I get the data from the form in special characters and save them as `<` `>` `=` `>=` `<=` `<>` in database using laravel?

Actually I intend to use them later as operators so it wouldn't work if I have them as special characters in database and saving them directly as that may be risky so how should I handle it?

Comment: Not sure if I've understood your question, but; [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: also u can add these special characters in "<" these format also . and when u want tot use it just remove " " Using string replace .

Answer (score 0):

Try those PHP functions before INSERT / UPDATE opration:

1. `strtr()`,
2. `str_replace()`,
3. `preg_replace()`.

If your texts comes from some WYSIWYG editor, those functions probably will be the best way to solve your problem.

If you don't use WYSIWYG check what is in your form fields values - maybe this is source of your problem and much simplier to handle.